# Cannot exit while loop with boolean condition c++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, boolean, exit

Hi this is my first post. I apologize if I'm not following certain rules or conventions. If that is the case please let me know.

I have a game which runs in a while loop until the score limit is reached by either player, at which point the other player has one last (iteration) chance to beat the first players score. However after the score limit is reached, the loop continues to run and the winner is never checked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int roll();
int playTurn(int);

int main(){

const int LIMIT = 5;
int whoseTurn = 1;
int pnts1 = 0;
int pnts2 = 0;
bool suddenDeath = false; //True when score limit is reached



while(!suddenDeath){

    if(pnts1 >= LIMIT || pnts2 >= LIMIT){                       //Limit was reached by previous player.
        suddenDeath == true;                                    //Next player has 1 turn to win

    }   

    if(whoseTurn == 1){
        pnts1 += playTurn(whoseTurn);                           //Play turn and tally points
        whoseTurn = 2;                                          //Swith player for next iteration
    }
    else if(whoseTurn == 2){
        pnts2 += playTurn(whoseTurn);
        whoseTurn = 1;
    }

    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl     //Display score
         << "Player 1 has " << pnts1 << " points" << endl
         << "Player 2 has " << pnts2 << " points" << endl
         << "-------------------------------------" << endl << endl;

};

if(pnts1 > pnts2)
    cout << "Congratulations Player 1! You won with a score of: " << pnts1 << " - " << pnts2;
else if(pnts2 > pnts1)
    cout << "Congratulations Player 2! You won with a score of: " << pnts2 << " - " << pnts1;
else if(pnts1 == pnts2)
    cout << "A tie! What are the chances?";

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Did you mean `suddenDeath = true;` instead of `suddenDeath == true;`?

Answer (score 5):

```
suddenDeath == true;
//          ^^
```

is an expression meaning "compare those two values", which is then thrown away. The C statement `42;` is equally valid, and equally useless <sup>(a)</sup>.

You want to *assign* the value, so you'd use:

```
suddenDeath = true;
//          ^
```

It's actually the *other* end of the much more common `if (a = 0)` problem where people assign rather than compare.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you're wondering *why* anyone in their right mind would allow this into a language, it actually allows for some powerful constructs with minimal code.

And, you've seen it before most likely. The statement `i++;` is such a beast. It's an expression giving `i` (which you throw away here) with the *side effect* that `i` is incremented afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
suddenDeath = true;
```

Use a single `=` for assignment. `==` is used for condition check.